# iOS Long String Stored in Keychain Gets Randomly Corrupted

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am fighting a rather pesky and illusive bug in my app. I am storing a long random string ( > 3200 characters ) in the iOS keychain using the Keychain wrapper [UYLPasswordManager](https://github.com/kharrison/UYLPasswordManager). After what seems like a completely random period of time, that value stored in the Keychain returns as a string of date rather than the long string that was originally stored.

Now, I say that it returns a string of a date instead of the long string, however it could very well be returning any number of strings that are not correct - I was only able to reproduce it once with debugging to see the erroneous value coming back from the Keychain.

Things I have tried:

1. A multitude of Keychain wrappers, each of which exhibits the issue eventually.
2. Combing through each character of code that writes to the Keychain to ensure the value is not being overwritten.

Beyond that, due to the illusive nature of the bug, I have not been able to attack it from a different angle because I have no idea where else to look. I am storing other strings in the Keychain that are much shorter which never seem to have a problem. Is there a known issue or anyone else with a similar experience with storing long strings in the Keychain?

I am using Swift 1.2 (the problem pre-dates v1.2) and the latest Xcode (stable).

**EDIT:** I am attempting to split the string into smaller chunks and save those each in the keychain to see if there is corruption or loss of that data over time. I will post back here with results.

**EDIT:** Ever since I split up the string into many small parts, I have not seen the issue. I am going to wait another week before I confirm the issue as resolved using this method. Also, I plan on filing a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having an issue storing a very long string, it appears breaking the string into many parts and storing smaller chunks has solved this issue. Hope it helps someone else!